# Include ignored file in the git repository

Tags: git

Suppose I'm setting up a website, and there are loads of images. These images won't change. But I would like that when any members of the team clone the project, they get the images so that they run the website immediately. Does this mean that I should add track the images as well? I'm just taking an example, it could be a jar in a java project or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  Track any file you need.  Git is more than happy to let you track non-source code files.

If you need something really big, you can also consider [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/). That versions which files are needed in git, but the files themselves are fetched separately, so their history does not take up space in everybody's repository.

Comment: This is good advice, but can become very unwieldy later on, especially when those "unchanging" binary blobs start changing. But that is a problem easily put off.

Comment: Its certainly no more unweildly than trying to maintain two separate sets of files - one in source control and one out.  When the images start changing, he can then use git to get them distributed out to the team.  One way or another they'll be downloading them.  Obviously files like user uploads and avatars will still need to be ignored.

Comment: @U2EF1: When those "unchanging" binary blobs start changing, you will be _very very glad that you've put them under version control._

Comment: @JanHudec Early on, sure. But an image directory can easily go through hundreds of gigabytes of change when packed in git, while most people only need the most recent several. This is what I would term unwieldy.

Comment: @U2EF1: Yes, for those cases there is [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)

Comment: @U2EF1 there's no indication he's working with anywhere near that volumne of images.  If there's a specific issue with a high volume of images, that should be a different, more specific question here.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Right! That's why I said this is good advice.